# Can I convert RDD to DataFrame in Glue?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

my lambda function triggers glue job by boto3 glue.start_job_run

and here is my glue job script

```
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
import sys
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from operator import add
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_extract, max

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("pyspark-etl")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,['s3_target_path_key','s3_target_path_bucket'])
bucket = args['s3_target_path_bucket']
fileName = args['s3_target_path_key']

inputFilePath = f"s3a://{bucket}/{fileName}"
finalFilePath = f"s3a://glu-job-final-juiceb"

print(bucket, fileName)

rdd = sc.textFile(inputFilePath)
rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" ")).map(lambda x : (x.split(" ")[0], 1)).reduceByKey(add)
df = rdd.toDF(schema=('rawEntities string, Count int'))
df = df.withColumn("Entities", regexp_extract(col("rawEntities"),'[^!".?@:,\'*…_()]+',0))
df = df.filter(col("Entities") != "")
df = df.select("Entities","Count").groupBy("Entities").agg(max("Count").alias("Count"))
df.write.mode("append").options(header='True').parquet(finalFilePath)
```

The Glue job error message is "AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'toDF'

After googling, I noticed that in glue "toDF" means DynamicFrame to DataFrame.

It's not meaning RDD to DataFrame.

How can I convert RDD to DataFrame In glue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define schema types using `toDF()`. By using `toDF()` method, we don't have the control over schema customization. Having said that, using `createDataFrame()` method we have complete control over the schema customization.

See below logic -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([ StructField('rawEntities', StringType()),  StructField('Count' , IntegerType())])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=<your rdd>, schema = schema)
```

Comment: Is this specific to `aws-glue`? Standard spark has a `schema` parameter on `RDD.toDF()`. Beside that, the error is an `AttributeError`

Comment: Not sure about `aws-glue`. But we follow similar approach while using `pyspark`, in both locally as well as `Databricks`